# gcc 4.7 fails to use pointer template parameter sometimes

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, compiler-bug

Complete (not)working example:

```
struct s { int i; };

template<const s* _arr>
class struct_array
{
public:
    static constexpr auto arr = _arr[0]; // works
    template<int >
    struct inner // line 9, without this struct, it works
    {    
    };
};

constexpr const s s_objs[] = {{ 42 }};

int main()
{
    struct_array<s_objs> t_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall constexpr.cpp -o constexpr
```

I get a running program with ideone's gcc 4.8.1, but 4.7.3 prints this to me:

```
constexpr.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class struct_array<((const s*)(& s_objs))>’:
constexpr.cpp:18:30:   required from here
constexpr.cpp:9:16: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
constexpr.cpp:9:16: error: could not convert template argument ‘(const s*)(& s_objs)’ to ‘const s*’
```

The last two lines are repeated 3 times. What's the reason, and is there any workaround to use my code on gcc 4.7.3?

Comment: I strongly suggest you try using a new compiler and avoid stupid workarounds for compiler bugs. Although that might not be very feasible in all situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a compiler bug to me.

I tried you example on gcc 4.1.2 ([codepad](http://codepad.org/OTCJGlBD)), and you have to explicitely note the variable as having external linkage (const imply internal linkage unless specified otherwise, the following code is C++03):

```
struct s { int i; };

template<const s* _arr>
class struct_array
{
public:
    static const s arr;
    template<int >
    struct inner
    {    
    };
};

template<const s* _arr>
const s struct_array<_arr>::arr = _arr[0];

// Notice the 'extern'
extern const s s_objs[] = {{ 42 }};

int main()
{
    struct_array<s_objs> t_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

I also have it working on gcc 4.8.1 [without](https://ideone.com/h8c0bA) C++11 enabled.

So, the workaround is:

change

```
constexpr const s s_objs[] = ...;
```

to

```
extern const s s_objs[] = ...;
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d68428eee20b43cd).

If you want the variable to be a static class member, then you have to specify it to have external linkage:

```
struct data
{
    static const s s_objs[1];
};

extern const s data::s_objs[1] = {{ 42 }};
```

This gives me a [warning on gcc 4.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f11be6f82ef9a045), not on 4.8. Also it [doesn't compile on Rise4Fun](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/zHt). So, I'm not sure whether this is pure standard or a bug in one of the compiler.

Comment: Wow, thanks! What would the declaration be if `s_objs` should be a static class member (of some class) instead of a global variable? Is this still possible? My compiler says that `extern` and `static` were conflicting...